# How to crawl a list of url without for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a batch of list of url, and I want to crawl some information on these url

```
daa = ['https://old.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/a2p1ew/', 'https://old.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/9zzo0e/', 'https://old.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/a31a6q/', ]

for y in daa:
uClient = requests.get(y, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
page_soup = soup(uClient.content, "html.parser")
time= page_soup.findAll("p", {"class":"tagline"})[0].time.get('datetime').replace('-', '')
```

And I works well to get all `time` I want. But I need to do it without for loop or I mean I need to `open` and write a file at next step but if I do it in the same loop, the output is weird. 
How do I get `time` without a for loop?

Comment: Does `open(file, 'a')` (appending to the end of a file) not satisfy?

Comment: What do you mean output is weird. It could help to show the output you are getting, and the output you’re trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you could do as stated above use the `open(file, 'a')`. Or what I like to do is append everything into a table, and then write the whole thing as a file.

```
import requests
import bs4 
import pandas as pd


results = pd.DataFrame()

daa = ['https://old.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/a2p1ew/', 'https://old.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/9zzo0e/', 'https://old.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/a31a6q/', ]

for y in daa:
    w=1
    uClient = requests.get(y, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
    page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(uClient.content, "html.parser")
    time= page_soup.findAll("p", {"class":"tagline"})[0].time.get('datetime').replace('-', '')

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[y, time]], columns=['url','time'])
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop = True)

result.to_csv('path/to_file.csv', index=False)
```